# Filter array after formatting a date inside the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

So I have an array, that I need to filter out the dates inside the array. Simply filtering it out with this:

```
sunday = events.filter(function(item){
  return (item.start.date == `Sunday`)
})
```

This works fine, the only issue is, that the date inside the array isn't formatted, the date format is as follows:

```
{ date: '2020-07-05' }
```

So how would I go about formatting that date to a weekday, then after, filter out the array dates by the now formatted date?

Edit: will put that i have been using moment to format other dates i have been using, just wasn't sure how to use the array filter with something formatted.

Comment: It might be a good practice to have all of the dates in your app represented the same way, as something like js Date or moment dates.  Do all the computation, filtering etc with those objects.  Change them to strings only at the level of the UI, where a human needs to see them.  In other words, transform the input array to moment dates as early as you can.

Comment: "the only issue is, that the date inside the array isn't formatted, the date format is as follows: { date: '2020-07-05' }" So... the date isn't formatted, but the date is formatted?

Comment: Try using `map` to convert to required format after the `filter`?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is take an array of week days

```
weekDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

Assuming that your object is something like this

```
eventsArr = [
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-05'
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-06'
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-07'
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-08'
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-09'
        }
    }

]
```

You can use the below code

```
eventsArr.filter(item => weekDays[new Date(item.start.date).getDay()]==='Sunday')
```

where you pass your date string to `new Date()` and `getDay()` method will give you the index of the week day which you can use to get the Week day from `weekDays` array to filter the data.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use :

```
sunday = events.filter(function(item){
let weekDay=new Date(item.start.date).toLocaleString('en-us', {weekday:'long'})
return (weekDay === "Sunday")
})
```

Here's an example:

```js
const events = [
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-19'
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-20'
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-21'
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-22'
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            date: '2020-07-26'
        }
    }

]
const sunday = events.filter(function(item){
let weekDay=new Date(item.start.date).toLocaleString('en-us', {weekday:'long'})
return (weekDay === "Sunday")
})
console.log("Array of sundays :", sunday)
```